# How to turn off text selection magic in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Text selection in the code editor Eclipse for the Mac is a nightmare. I never remember having these problems on Windows so it may well be Mac specific There is a lot of "special magic" that makes it complete counter intuitive, where text selection selects ever larger objects such as paragraphs if you repeat an action in stead of just moves a selection cursor around to the next word delimiter.

- select text to the left of the cursor: SHIFT + ALT + Left Arrow. You select the text. Do the same thing again, and in stead of selecting the next word, you select a paragraph
- select text to right of the cursor: SHIFT + ALT + Left Arrow. Then, undo SHIFT + ALT + Right Arrow. You have now select both the original text and the word to the left of the original cursor position

So, is there a way to turn this magic off and just go to a predictable kind of text selection? Predictable in my mind is
CMD + Left Arrow Select until next delimiter left. Do the same thing with the Right Arrow after that means move the selection cursor to the right. etc

Comment: Is this a rant or a question?

Comment: It's a question. Even though I admit to some rantish elements

Comment: So maybe edit down it to talk about your actual specific problem, instead of mostly going on about vaguely specified "annoying magic"? Remember that when skimming through the list of questions, mousing over a title usually gives people the first paragraph of your question. Your first paragraph contains no useful information.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Done

Comment: As an aside: on OS X, Cmd+Left/Right moves to the start / end of the line. That said, Opt+Arrow should indeed move by words, not expand the selection. (Which is not a standard editor action.